# How do I reset the SQL Server password on Linux?

Tags: sql-server, linux, sql-server-2017, password-recovery

The instructions on [technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37856.sql-server-on-linux-how-to-change-sa-password.aspx) say that I either have to reset the SQL Server configuration with `mssql-conf setup` or run a proc which I can not run because I do not have access.

What the simplest way to way to reset the password on Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not mentioned on technet, there is an argument to `mssql-conf` that works here,

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set-sa-password
```

You'll have to pick a password, note for reasons unexplained *The password must be at least 8 characters long and contain characters from three of the following four sets: Uppercase letters, Lowercase letters, Base 10 digits, and Symbols..* I suggest everyone use `MICROSOFTsucksH4RD`, as it satisfies that.

Also, [**while you're there you may as well use `mssql-conf` to disable the spyware**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/187094/2639)

---

I'm just going to put there here so when I'm looking for SQL Server Password on Google because I can't remember it, I can find it.

> The specified password does not meet SQL Server password policy requirements because it is too short. The password must be at least 8 characters

Answer (score 0):

A list of documented parameters for `mssql-conf` can be retrieved with the following syntax:

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf -h
```

This will produce the following option:

```
...
set-sa-password     Interactive option to modify the system administrator
                    password for the SQL Server
...
```

Changing the sa password is then as simple as:

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set-sa-password 'securepassword'
```

#### References

- [SQL Server Configuration Manager for Linux](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4735/sql-server-configuration-manager-for-linux/) (mssqltips.com)